# NULL is displayed as an output of executing bcp command in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I'm building a `query` to be executed with `bcp` utility in SQL.

After executing a query I'm getting a `NULL` result as an output.

I already asked a question with related discussion, but the question was concentrated on different kind of error.

This is my query:

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @bcpCommand VARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @sharedDevFolder VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @environment VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @customerCode VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @parserConfig VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @bucketAssign VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @dateFormat VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @input INT
DECLARE @RC INT

SET @sharedDevFolder = '\\REMOTE_SERVER\DATAFOLDER\'
SET @input = 201507
SET @environment = 'DEV'
SET @customerCode = '123'
SET @parserConfig = '100'
SET @bucketAssign = 'Bucket1'
SET @fileName = 'Transaction-' + 
                    @environment + '-' + 
                    @customerCode + '-' + 
                    @parserConfig + '-' + 
                    @bucketAssign + '-' + 
                    @dateFormat + '.txt'

SET @query = 
        'SELECT ''Transaction Unique ID'',''Transaction Date'', ''Person Unique ID'' 
        UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS ''Transaction Unique ID'', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,Date,1),101) AS ''Transaction Date'', 
        NULL AS ''Person Unique ID'' FROM tblChromeRiverInitData WHERE YYYYMM = ''' + CAST(@input as VARCHAR) + ''''

select @query

    --need to change @sharedDevFolder depending on a server environment
SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "' + @query + '" queryout "'
    set @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @sharedDevFolder + @fileName + '" -c  -T -t^| -r\n'

EXEC @RC = master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

This is a final query syntax I display to make sure my query is correct:

`SELECT 'Transaction Unique ID','Transaction Date', 'Person Unique ID' 
        UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS 'Transaction Unique ID', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,Date,1),101) AS 'Transaction Date', 
        NULL AS 'Person Unique ID' FROM tblChromeRiverInitData WHERE YYYYMM = '201507'`

And it looks to me it is just fine.

However, when executing

`SELECT 'Transaction Unique ID','Transaction Date', 'Person Unique ID' UNION ALL SELECT NULL AS 'Transaction Unique ID', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,Date,1),101) AS 'Transaction Date', NULL AS 'Person Unique ID' FROM tblChromeRiverInitData WHERE YYYYMM = @input`

by itself, everything works fine

What can be wrong?

Comment: You have data in your table matching with where where?

Comment: try to follow this article https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a5be5f3f-1a93-4340-89fe-652bfba2af64/bcp-query-returns-null-result?forum=transactsql

Comment: Actually, my bcp command executes if I have `select * from tblChromeRiverInitData` as a query. I decided to change the query to be composed differently due to some other requirements. And that's where I start having the problem

Comment: you modified query works independently or not?

Comment: Yes, my modified query works independently. I updated my question

Comment: I found the problem, but not sure how to fix it. The problem is in `@filename` variable. The `bcp` does not recognize the string used. I'm trying to compose the right string combination, but it does not seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your issue, or if it's just what I encountered when I tried to duplicate your issue.  When I set @query I put part of my select statement on one line, then hit enter and put more of my statement on the next line.  When I ran this I got output that said "usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile...NULL."  However, when I put the statement on a single line everything worked fine.  I don't think it's an issue with data type sizes, because I tried increase @query and @bcpcommand to 4000 and still got the same error.  I hope this helps!

Comment: I have everything on the same line

Comment: OK.  I think the reason mine didn't work is it was actually trying to execute each piece on a new line in the command line.  I'll see if I can come up with another answer.

Comment: I was able to duplicate your issue more closely.  I think the issue is your filename.  The @dateFormat variable is being declared, but not set.  When I removed it from the file name everything seemed to work.